# Partial configuration of utf8 collations and charsets on MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I've been trying various configurations to force charset and collations to utf8. However, everything I tried has failed and some settings reflect the latin charset or collation.

This is MySQL 5.6 on CentOS 6 from IUS repository.

My config on /usr/share/mysql/my.cnf

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Settings through Heidi

[image]

From the MySQL client

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'coll%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I did not have any issues in 5.1 though.

**Update #1**

I've put `default-character-set = utf8`, in `client`, `mysqld` and `mysql` section of `my.cnf` and rebooted the MySQL service. Still the same thing, a mix of latin and utf8.

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'coll%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Update #2**

My issues related to migrating a database using Migration Wizard through MySQL Workbench. The resulting database has collations and charsets that I don't want. If I run the produced script through Heidi, I get the same result as the migration result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hard coding the collation and character set that I wanted in the generated scripts.

ie. when creating the database and adding columns, specifying the collation and character set where necessary, utf8_unicode_ci, utf8...

Answer (score 0):

`init-connect` is ignored when you connect as `root` (or other `SUPER` user).

In your `my.cnf` (`my.ini`) files, add this under `[mysql]` or `[client]`:

```
default-character-set = utf8
```

(I don't know if Heidi will override that -- find out how it does the "connect".)

**Addenda**

character_set_database and _server are not necessarily an issue. _client, *connection* and _results are used to say how the bytes *in the client* are encoded.  You say what the table contains by adding `CHARACTER SET utf8` in `CREATE TABLE`.

Aside from the settings being like you show them, what symptoms do you have of messed up text?  Do this with some column with non-English text:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...
```

to show what is actually stored.

Comment: I'm using Workbench's Migration Wizard and it's defaulting to collations and charsets that I don't want. When I output the script, it doesn't show any hard coded collations/charsets. If I run the produced scripts in Heidi, I still get a default collation of latin_swedish_ci for the tables.